# Rails: Unable to save image with paperclip due to content-type inode/x-empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, content-type

In my rails application, I am trying to save images to AWS S3 bucket using Paperclip gem. For some of my .jpg images it does not store them because their content-type is 'inode/x-empty'. How can I force Paperclip to save them anyways ?

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true

   has_attached_file :file, styles: { small: '120x50', medium: '350x350' }
   validates_attachment :file, presence: true, content_type: { content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/ }
   validates :file_fingerprint, uniqueness: { scope: :owner_id, :message => "already exists in the database." }

   before_post_process :rename_file

   protected
   def rename_file
     curr = file.instance_read(:file_name)
     succ = "#{SecureRandom.hex}#{File.extname(curr).downcase}"
     file.instance_write(:file_name, succ)
   end
end
```

I have tried following solutions found on web, but nothing worked:

1. Added `validates_attachment_content_type :file, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'application/x-empty', 'inode/x-empty']`
2. Added `do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :file`
3. Created initializer `class MediaTypeSpoofDetector` to `def spoofed? false`
4. Set `Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings] = { :jpg => "image/jpeg" }` in **paperclip.rb** under **/initializers/**

Any help is appriciated